# How do you specify the code behind the mocked AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-mock

I'm currently in the phase of unit-testing my lambdas and this is the first time I'm doing this, so please bear with me.

I've done my researches about this, and I think I managed to pinpoint down to which package I should use and which method.

As far as I know, `aws-sdk-mock` is the way to go. It seems complete and well-documented, so there's no problem in that direction. The only issue I have with it is the lack of documentation for AWS Lambda Invoke mockings.

The main issue I have is with mocking a specific function whose code is stored in the same project as the test.

i.e: I have a `lambda.ts`:

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event: any) => {
    const body = event.body;
    //do things with body
    return {
      statusCode:200,
      body: "OK"
    }
}
```

How do I correctly mock this?
I started a `lambda.test.ts` that looks like this :

```
import AWSMock from "aws-sdk-mock"
import AWS from "aws-sdk"

beforeAll(async (done) => {
  //get requires env vars
  done()
})

describe("Calling lambda", () => {
  it("should reject API call because of missing arguments", async () => {
    AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS)
    AWSMock.mock("Lambda", "invoke", async (params, callback) => {
        const lambda = new AWS.Lambda()
        await lambda.invoke({
            FunctionName: 'lambda',
            ...?
        }).promise()
    })
  })
})
```

I don't know how to indicate that the code that's behind this mocked lambda is available somewhere.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you testing your Lambda or testing something else that calls your Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

May not answer your question, but you haven't gotten any answers eithter. I would only declare dependencies in the lambda. Then inject the dependencies into a separate class (myClass) or file that I can fully unit test.  I.e.:

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event: any) => {
    const body = event;
    //Declare dependencies
    const myDependency1 = new Dependency1();
    const myClass = new MyClass(myDependency1);
    return myClass.whatever(event):
    }
}

describe("Calling myClass", () => {
  it("should reject API call because of missing arguments", async () => {
    const body = event;
    //Declare dependencies
    const myDependency1 = new Dependency1();
    const myClass = new MyClass(myDependency1);
    myClass.whatever(event):
    }
    })
  })
})
```